# Order by columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these data:

```
hour1 | hour2 | hour3 | date
h1      h2      h3      d1
h4      h5      h6      d2
```

Regardless of the values (without using `order by`) I want to use a query to show them with this order:

```
h_value | date
h1        d1
h2        d1
h3        d1
h4        d2
h5        d2
h6        d2
```

I have tried many queries and statements like union , join, etc ... but none of them works. The last code that I have tried:

```
SELECT test.h1 as h_value,
        test.h2 as h_value,
        test.h3 as h_value,
        test.date
      FROM test
```

The result of this code is:

```
h_value| h_value| h_value| date
h1       h2       h3       d1
h4       h5       h6       d2
```

Any solution?
(Notice: Ignore table data, Only in the order of the specified columns:

```
h_value | date
row1col1  date1
row1col2  date1
row1col3  date1
row2col1  date2
row2col2  date2
row2col3  date2
```

I hope you know what I mean)

**EDIT 1**
look, I can't use order by or use where because both of them are tested and result was false, if my data on table is like this:

```
hour1 | hour2 | hour3 | date
5:00    7:00    4:00    2018/10/09
3:30    8:00    4:00    2018/09/20
7:00    9:00    6:00    2018/11/10
```

How do I suppose to order this data as I want? Its a simple question to understand!

Comment: why is the use of `order by` denied? SQL can only produce data in a specific order if you tell it to do that, otherwise it will be unordered (i.e. you cannot guarantee what order it will be presented UNLESS you use order by)

Comment: because in order by with got wrong result, out data is not ordered and it may inserted a date from few days ago and next day and etc ...

Comment: Down voted for sounding arrogant. That's not how you ask help.

Comment: The original suggestions were based on "h1" "h2"... etc, THEN you revealed "5:00" "7:00" etc. Answers are based on the information you provide (e.g. originally you had MySQL, which does not yet support "unpivot"). It then takes time to realize you have changed the database and sample data - we are volunteering our time so other things occur in our lives too.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post, @MSHDeveloper. It looks like you have found an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE Unpivot in case of sql server:

```
    select date, hvalue
from student
unpivot
(
  hvalue
  for val in (hour1, hour2, hour3)
) u
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e0d2/2

Comment: No not like this. I told you ignore table data. if I have 100 rows this code will hangup my sql server by repeating it 100 time. this clause can not be perform: (where date = d1)

Comment: if it is sqlserver then why your question tag mysql?

Comment: yes, is it mysql or ms sql server - it makes a big difference to solution choices

Comment: I've modified the answer with a demo - recheck it

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Sever you coudl use `unpivot` llike this:

```
SELECT h_value, adate
FROM   
   (SELECT h1,h2,h3,adate
   FROM test) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (h_value FOR src IN   
      (h1,h2,h3)  
)AS unpvt
order by adate, h_value;
```

But you retain the issue that SQL **requires** the use of `order by` to guarantee an ordered result.

---

original suggestion (when db was listd as MySQL)

```
SELECT
    test.h1 AS h_value, test.date
FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT
    test.h2 AS h_value, test.date
FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT
    test.h3 AS h_value, test.date
FROM test
ORDER BY
    h_value, date
```

Comment: Just a quick fix, your order by needs to be: `ORDER BY h_value, date`.

Comment: my data is not ordered in none of columns! it gives me wrong result

Comment: what data? the data you have presented here would sort correctly... so show some data you actually use

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting an error with this query? Take a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ee59/10)

Comment: in mysql if my data is not ordered like sample in EDIT 1 I get false result.

Comment: OP edited his question to include the actual data of `h_value` column. You need to convert this column to time for the `ORDER BY` to work as sorting of hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong preference for using `cross apply` instead of `unpivot` for unpivoting.  Basically, `apply` is very powerful and can do many things.  This is a good way to learn about the functionality.

However, if you want the results in a particular order, *you have to use `order by`*.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless you explicitly insist.

So, I would go for:

```
select s.date, h.h_value
from student s cross apply
     (values (hour1, 1), (hour2, 2), (hour3, 3)
     ) h(hour, ord)
order by s.date, h.ord;
```

Comment: for T-SQL this works, but UNPIVOT is available in more than just T-SQL

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . lateral joins are supported by most major databases now, and they are much more useful than `unpivot`.

Comment: Lateral joins are, yes. I was referring to the use of `values ( .... )` inside the apply operator. That isn't supported by all. Just a note. Nothing more.